# Changing the number of integers on a output value after the decimal point

Tags: c#

So I'm learning and practicing WP7 application development.

I'm working with integers (currency), and it seems to always display four integers after the decimal place. I'm trying to cut it down to just either ONE or TWO decimal places.

I've been trying to use the   `"my variable.ToString("C2")"`     (C for Currency, 2 for number of ints after the decimal)

I'm probably missing something obvious, but please help

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about looking at string.Format method for Decimal, Double, and Currency types..?

Comment: Did you try just .ToString("c") ? It should convert your value into currency format, witch proper number of decimal digits.

Comment: did you translate error message from VisualStudia? you cannot use variable before it's initializing (:

Comment: The code you show only tries to return a currency **sign**. How do you display the **value**?

Comment: Hi Hans, the value is being displayed in Windows Phone Eumulator

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes I tried that Marcin, still same output though do you need more screen grabs / skype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "C" format string defines the currency specifier as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). This will include the currency symbol for the current culture, or for a specific culture if supplied, e.g.

```
double amount = 1234.5678;
string formatted = amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
// This gives $1234.56
```

In your case, it seems that you have a limited set of currency symbols that you support, so I would suggest using the fixed point format specifier "F" instead. By default this will give you 2 decimal points, but you can specify a number to vary this, e.g.

```
double amount = 1234.5678;
string formatted = amount.ToString("F");
// This gives 1234.56
formatted = amount.ToString("F3");
// This gives 1234.567
```

Using the fixed point specifier will give you control over the number of decimal points and enable you to concatenate the currency symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal number = new decimal(1000.12345678);
string text = number.ToString("#.##");
```

Output:

```
1000,12
```

An other way:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
decimal val = new decimal(1000.12345678);
string text = val.ToString("c", nfi);
```

When formatting a currency, [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) allows specifying following properties as well:

- CurrencyDecimalDigits
- CurrencyDecimalSeparator
- CurrencyGroupSeparator
- CurrencyGroupSizes
- CurrencyNegativePattern
- CurrencyPositivePattern
- CurrencySymbol

See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN for more examples

Comment: Tried this, it didn't produce any error but still displayed 4 decimal places.     e.g  £40.0000

Comment: Where it is displaying 4 decimal places? In debugger/watch window/textbox/web page? Basically show a code which you've used

Comment: it displays four decimals in the WP emulator, when the application is being Run

Comment: See updated answer, basically try out manually create and specify `NumberFormatInfo`

Comment: Please use `Decimal` not `Double`.

Comment: @AlexD Using decimal is an issue orthogonal to your problem. `double` should not be used for values, like currency, where decimal digits play an important role.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would add to "sll" answer is to pay attention on [Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/d8ztz0sa%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (they often forget to mantion this), like this (example)

```
string text = val.ToString("#.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I'd have to add a 'Culture' namespace just for this?

Comment: @AlexD: System.Globalization mapespace

Comment: Yeah, I can add the namespace alright ;) but its the structuring of your answer to correlate with the code I'm working on is what I find complicated about this Culture thing

Comment: @AlexD: there is nothing complicated with this stuff (at least if we use .NET technology). The thing is that if we work woth floating point numbers, imo, it's always important to pay attention on culture we use. For example: delimeters in English and French culture are different (in one it's a '.', in another it's a ','), so if you store double on english system and pass data to french system you will get unpredictable results on deserializaiton.

Comment: @Tigran I understand what you are trying to say. But I'm using consistent English delimiters. Why would I use French? Do you use Skype by any chance?

Comment: This is a way to ensure that your code works in multi-culture environment too.

Comment: @AlexD: yes I have Skype, but use usually for personal use and not for business. Do you need some help ?

Comment: -Yeah would be great, only if you're not busy though. Think I've added you.

Answer (score 0):

```
double total = 526.4134
string moneyValue = total.ToString("c");
```

This will display it in this format: $#.##

Comment: Tried this! no errors appear but still displays 4 decimal places when being run in the emulator